# Vim function somehow adds Ctrl-j to macro?

Tags: macro, functions

I've written a short vim function that allows me to edit the contents of vim registers:

```
fun! RegBuff()
    let vimstuff = "/tmp/vimstuff"
    if !isdirectory(vimstuff)
        call mkdir(vimstuff)
    endif
    let reg = getchar()
    let reg = nr2char(reg)
    exec 'au BufWrite vimreg-* exec "normal gg0\"'.reg.'yy"'
    exec '1new '.vimstuff.'/vimreg-'.reg
    exec 'normal ggdG"'.reg.'P'
endfun
nnoremap <leader><F2> :call RegBuff()<CR>
```

If I do, for instance, `qqi1234^[` to record insert 1234 into the q register, and then call my function `:call RegBuff()` or `<leader><F2>`, I get a nice little window at the top with the contents of the buffer. Cool. if I edit it to be `i12345678^[`, save the file and exit, and then do `@q`, it properly now enters insert mode and inserts 12345678. Also cool.

The problem is that I generally run vim in tmux, and for some reason after executing this macro it switches to the tmux pane below vim. This is as if the macro is additionally running `<Ctrl>j` after the macro is run.

If I go back to the vim pane, and type `"qp` to see whats in the `q` register it looks totally normal, it just contains what I expect to be in there.

Why does there appear to be this extra key code sent after I call the macro?

Comment: Are you writing the buffer? It might be, that when writing the buffer, Vim writes an additional EOL. Try setting 'nofixendofline'

Comment: Thanks for the help Christian. I am writing the buffer, which triggers the BufWrite autocommand that copies the first line of the buffer back into the register. Neither putting `set nofixendofline` in the function or setting it manually doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Note that you can call `:echomsg @q` to see what is in register `q`, including special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came across this question is looking into a different `^J` phenomenon.

#### Register Situation

In your `RegBuff` function, you yank text of the buffer into the register with `yy`. This is linewise yank, thus it appends the newline `^J` to the register.

Printing the register (`"qp`) will not show the newline, but it will *insert a line* below cursor on which it prints the text. You can see the `^J` explicitly by using the `:reg {arg}` command (`:reg q` shows the contents of `q`).

#### Solution

Change the linewise yank (`yy` -- yank line) to be a motion yank (`y$` -- yank to end of line):

```
"Original linewise
exec 'au BufWrite vimreg-* exec "normal gg0\"'.reg.'yy"'
```

becomes

```
"Updated to motion
exec 'au BufWrite vimreg-* exec "normal gg0\"'.reg.'y$"'
```

Comment: I had no idea that `^J` was also interpreted as a newline character. Thanks for the response! (also you've got a typo in your explaination, the second `yy` should be `y$`, I can't edit it because the edit is less than 6 characters.

Comment: You've got a typo @BrianAlbertMonroe in your typo explanation.  :D